# How to count loop execution with local variables and user defined function? C Language

Tags: c, variables, global

Please help as I am a beginner here. In this program, main asks the user to enter an integer. If the integer is positive, the loop will continue, and ask to enter another integer. The user-defined function named "myfunction" displays in output how many times the do-while loop has been called. I used variable loopCount++ to increment this count each time. This program works correctly, but I have just been given a new challenge: do this without using any global variables. Turns out I have one global var... int loopCount.  I have no idea how to accomplish this using local variables but I sure do want to know. PLEASE help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int loopCount;

int main()
{
int number;

  do{

     printf("Enter a number: ");
      scanf("%i", &number);
       loopCount++;
        myfunction();

  }while(number > 0);
    exit(0);
  }


int myfunction(){
  printf("The loop has been called %d times\n\n", loopCount);
}
```

Comment: i get that.. if you see, i used loopCount++ within the while loop, but how can I count loops IN main, while using that same integer in the other function to display "The loop has been called ___ number of times"   i feel it simply cannot be done without a global variable.

Comment: just move the variable `loopCount` to the `main()` function, then pass that variable to `myfunction()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make `loopCount` a variable that is local to `main`, and pass it to `myfunction` as an argument, like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int number;
  int loopCount = 1;

  do{

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%i", &number);
    myfunction(loopCount++);

  }while(number > 0);
  exit(0);
}


int myfunction(count){
  printf("The loop has been called %d times\n\n", count);
}
```

It's also probably worth pointing out that this code could use better error handling - if you're not sure what I mean, try typing a letter at the prompt (instead of a number).

Comment: I also condensed the loopCount post-increment into the call to myfunction() - you could just as readily leave those as distinct operations.